# Maven profiles to point to different config files using single pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I need to use multiple config files ( .properties files ) based on environment in which software is being tested.

For this I've planned to use **Maven Profiles**. But I'm not getting how to mention different config file names under the same pom.xml

e.g.

**mvn -Ptest**  *should run test.properties*

**mvn -Pstage** *should run stage.properties*

**mvn -Pprod**  *should run prod.properties*

Comment: What kind of project do you have? Spring/Spring Boot ? Apart from that I can't recommend that...

Comment: I've got Mobile automation project ( with appium ) and would like to pass either of Android / iOS properties to run tests on respective device

Comment: I would suggest to take a look here...https://khmarbaise.github.io/multienv-maven-plugin/